# Как сменить название голосового канала? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
if after.channel != None:
    if after.channel.id == 970690442997932146:
        category = after.channel.category
        
        channel2 = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(
            name = f'{ member.display_name }', 
            category = category,
        )
        await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect = True)
        await member.move_to(channel2)

        def check(x, y, z): return len(channel2.members) == 0
        
        await self.bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check)
        await channel2.delete()

@commands.command()
async def lock(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  
        await channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=970690442553327706), connect = False)
        await ctx.send('Канал закрыт')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")
        return

@commands.command()
async def unlock(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  
        await channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,id=970690442553327706), connect = True)
        await ctx.send('Канал открыт')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")
        return
```

Надо добавить команду по смене названия канала, на то что человек напишет

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Для чего остальной код приложен к вопросу? Вы же нашли в документации необходимую информацию для создания остальных функций. В чем здесь проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.